# Which is the best approch for numerical input in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance

I have a textbox where user enters an ID. This ID is stored as an integer.

So, my question is, should I validate the textbox after user enters a value and clicks "Search" button **or** should user be allowed to enter only numbers?

I do have solution for both in JavaScript/jQuery. But I am not sure which is good in terms of performance.

Comment: If the user has to enter only numbers,then make him enter only numbers.From a usability perspective,hinting the user about this might be good.

Comment: You must validate it both, on client side and again on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a functionality PoV, you should validate that the user may only input numbers in a numeric field, so that there is data consistency. Also, in my experience, users like it when you validate the input right when they're typing it.

From a safety PoV, you should server validate it to guarantee data consistency in the database.

In conclusion you should validate it both ways. It shouldn't be excessively resource consuming as to be forced to choose one option only.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate the input on the server and not rely solely on JavaScript validation. This is because JavaScript is not "trusted" for validation since it can be disabled by the user